# I want an auto incremented column "ID"starting with 001 in mysql-php? Using phpmyadmin how to do that

Tags: php, mysql, sql, alter, zerofill

I want to start my auto incrementation of column from 001,002,003 like that ..plz tell me how to do that..

Using phpMyadmin.

```
 1. ID
 2. 001
 3. 002
 4. 003
 5. .
 6. .
 7. .
 like above shown..
```

Comment: Use 1,2,3,4,5 etc as your autoincrement values, and add leading zeroes only when you need to for display purposes

Comment: Why not just starting from 1 ? You can format that to 001 , 002 in PHP.

Comment: using phpMyAdmin - no way. You would need to alter your script to INSERT max(ID)+1, because it's not a valid autoincrement way, even more when starting with first record `1. ID` and second `2. 001`

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran how to? what do you mean format? will u plz tell?

Comment: [sprint()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) is a good place to look for formatting numbers for display with leading zeroes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [**ZEROFILL**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) attribute of column.

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName CHANGE `columnName` `columnName` INT(3) ZEROFILL;
```